# How to convert IStream Resource to CBitmap on MFC

Tags: mfc, msdn, wpd

I am working with WPD (Windows Portable Devices) API, and I have a problem.  I have obtained images, video, mp3 objects on a device, and now I want to show a thumbnail of images on `CListCtrl`.  I have used the following to get `Stream`  of image objects:

```
pd_resource->GetStream(objectID,WPD_RESOURCE_THUMBNAIL, STGM_READ, &optimal_transfer_size, &src_data_stream)
```

How do I convert this `Stream` resource to `CBitmap`?

Please help me! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a resource here that shows how to convert IStream to HBITMAP.

Hope this helps:
http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2011/08/04/display-images-as-you-type-in-cpp/

Comment: Thank's goths, but i want to ask again that above the way to get images's thumbnail is a true idea?

Comment: For that it is better to use GetSupportedResources before calling GetStream to ensure that WPD_RESOURCE_THUMBNAIL is supported.

Comment: OK, i used above GetStream function to get stream data, output is src_data_stream, after that i call to function on link you shared, IWICBitmapSource* ipBitmap= LoadBitmapFromStream(src_data_stream), but ipBitmap return NULL, can you help me?

Comment: I think first you must try loading full bitmap to determine where the problem is. Whether with thumbnail or with the process of loading bitmap.

Comment: Can you guide me detail?

Comment: Sorry. Can't help in detail.